# Google Site Translate widget with custom dictionary

Tags: dictionary, google-translate

I need to modify translation output for specific translation pairs (for example 'en' -> 'ru'). I found entry on [official Google Translate Blog](https://translate.googleblog.com/2012/05/now-you-can-polish-up-googles.html), but it's old and now you can't get "customization meta tag". There is another way to acomplish that?